# Swift iOS: Cannot add view programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface

I'm trying to add checkboxes (library views) to container view. But they do not appear.

```
@IBOutlet weak var checkBoxesContainerView: UIView! //this is view where I', trying to add checkboxes

    func initialize() {
        let optionsList = webFormElement.possibleValues
        var latestCheckBox: Checkbox? = nil
        for option in optionsList {
            var checkBox = Checkbox(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)) //creating checkbox programmatically - it's custom view, but it's works in another places
            checkBox.borderLineWidth = 1
            checkBox.uncheckedBorderColor = UIColor.black
            checkBoxesContainerView.addSubview(checkBox)

            checkBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
            checkBox.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true
            checkBox.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 20).isActive = true

            if(latestCheckBox == nil) {
                checkBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkBoxesContainerView.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                checkBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkBoxesContainerView.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            } else {
                checkBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: latestCheckBox!.topAnchor, constant: 8).isActive = true
                checkBox.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: latestCheckBox!.leadingAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            }

            latestCheckBox = checkBox
        }
    }
```

Please help! No checkboxes at the screen (

Comment: You are showing how you constrain the "checkBoxes" to the container view, but you're not showing constraints for the container view itself. Most likely, it has ended up with a size of `0,0` and so nothing outside of it is visible.

Comment: Where do you call func `initialize()`? Are you sure `optionsList` array is not empty?

Comment: Make sure you're calling `initialize()`, and make sure  `webFormElement.possibleValues` is not empty (otherwise there are no checkBoxes to create). Other than that, when `latestCheckBox` is not `nil`, you probably want the next constraint to be `equalTo: latestCheckBox!.bottomAnchor` (instead of `.topAnchor`), or your checkBoxes will overlap.

Comment: I've tried without frame. The same result (

Comment: @ВладимирФишер - put a `print(option)` statement as the first line after `for option in optionsList` and confirm that the code is actually executing.

Answer (score -1):

I think the problem is you are mixing Frame and Autolayout. Use either one but not both.

Try to initialize your Checkbox like this `CheckBox()` and add these along with `widthAnchor` and `heightAnchor`

```
checkBox.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: checkBoxesContainerView.topAnchor).isActive = true

checkBox.leftAncho.constraint(equalTo: checkBoxesContainerView.leftAnchor).isActive = true
```

Comment: As soon as this line: `checkBox.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false` executes, the existing frame is ignored. The posted code is already setting width and height anchors, so instantiating the view with `CheckBox()` or `Checkbox(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20))` doesn't matter.

Comment: true, but he has `leadingAnchor`. This is common problem. It should be `leftAnchor`.  And he should not mix frame and autolayout. It is confusing.

Comment: `leadingAnchor` is recommended over `leftAnchor` as it will cooperate with locales (RTL vs LTR). See this answer for a more complete description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/32981750/6257435 --- I do agree that mixing explicit frames with auto layout is a bad idea, but that is not what is causing his checkBox views to not show up.

Comment: do you have any constraint for `checkBoxesContainerView`? Also, your `topAnchor` constant is 8. Are you sure it is not out of bound of `checkBoxesContainerView`? I would look at `checkBoxesContainerView` and make sure it has proper size and constraint.