# What do trailing and leading edges mean in SwiftUI?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui

I can't find a source that says what the definition of trailing and leading edges mean in SwiftUI

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The same as they mean in [`UIKit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32981532/difference-between-leftanchor-and-leadinganchor/32981750#32981750).  They are a locale-dependent way of specifying horizontal edges.  In a left-to-right locale, such as English, the leading edge is the left and the trailing edge is the right.  In a right-to-left locale (e.g. Hebrew), the leading edge is on the right and the trailing edge is on the left.

By specifying spacing in terms of leading/trailing rather than left/right you can ensure that your layout is consistent regardless of the user's locale.

Answer (score 1):

Trailing edge - like it's right side of view. When you want to view should have left padding 20 from left side of view controller its means you should set padding for leading edge. this is for right side same. It's just sides of view.

There great examples for clearly understand [link](https://www.calincrist.com/blog/2020-05-02-beginners-guide-to-view-modifiers-swiftui/).